# How to recreate default (Document) content type

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, powershell, designer-workflow, content-type

I am using SharePoint online and created 4 custom content types on 1 SharePoint site in the tenant.  I have a document library and it has these 4 different content types applied to the documents uploaded in the library.

I would now like to reverse the setup and go back to the default content type (Document) and remove all content types on the tenant.

I think i need to do the following but not sure how to go back and select the Document content type that was originally used.

1. Change the default content type to 'Document' so any new documents uploaded will have the content type of Document applied.
2. Change the content type values in the SharePoint document library to the new value of "Document".  I suspect this can be done via Powershell or SharePoint designer.  But still a newbie in both areas and have over 500 items to change.
3. Delete the 4 content types (site settings > Content types > Delete)
4. Turn off the management of content types on the site (document library > library settings > advanced > turn off management of content types)

Anyone able to provide any assistance/pointers.

Comment: You are on right path...First you have to change content type of all documents in library (Using Powershell/C#/JSOM). Then delete all custom CT from library.